# Angularjs framework usage in angular 7

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular7

My application is very big which is created in angular 7. I saw the below dashboard framework which is created in angularjs (using bower for dependency management) .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-dashboard-framework

I want to integrate this dashboard framework into my angular 7 application, is it possible to do it? 
If yes, how and if no, is there any way where i can port this to higher angular versions.

Comment: Check this link: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AngularJS and Angular 7 both are different in terms of many methodologies. 
At the End TypeScript code converted into JavaScript after compilation. But when you will merge the code you will have to need some extra configuration changes which will take your too much time.

The best solution will be :
1 Convert your AngularJS code into Angular TypeScript https://angular.io/guide/upgrade manually.

Angular Documentation provided doc to update Angular Version but it is for TS to TS only. https://update.angular.io/#2.0:8.0